# CruiseControl.net checking files in source control (into different projects) after building them

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, dependencies

I have set up an automated build server - so far so good. Now I want to sort out dependencies. We have several DLL files that are included in many (unrelated) projects, and I want to set up CruiseControl.NET to first build our DLL files and then "check them in" other projects in SVN, so when they get built, they will always use the last version of DLL files.

Is something like that even possible? Is there a better way to keep dependencies sorted over several projects on many computers?

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is to have a project in cruise control for the common dll, it uses a source control trigger and builds whenever changes are checked in.

On the dependant project, I have the source control trigger, but also a [project trigger](http://ccnetlive.thoughtworks.com/ccnet/doc/CCNET/Project%20Trigger.html) so any checkin on the common.dll causes the common.dll to be rebuilt, which in turn triggers a build of the dependant project.

Comment: How does the dependant project know where to look for the freshly built common.dll?